# Angular form keep returning false (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, angular2-forms, model-driven

I have a form in Angular 2 which I'm validating by the model-driven way. I wanna know how do I change the status from false to true, because I have the rules of validation and even if the user fills everything right, it keeps returning me invalid (false). Here's the HTML code.

```
<div class="wrap-page">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate class="form-contato" (ngSubmit)="enviarMensagem(myForm.value, myForm.valid)">
    <div class=row>
      <div class="col s12">
        <h4> Contato </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m12 l6">
        <label> Nome: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" formControlName="nome" class="forms-econ" required placeholder="ex: José Silva">
        <div class="div-validar">
          <span [hidden]="myForm.controls.nome.valid || (myForm.controls.nome.pristine && !submitted)">
            Nome Inválido (mínimo 3 caracteres).
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 l6">
        <label> E-mail: </label>
        <input type="email" class="forms-econ" formControlName="email" required name="email" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
          placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com">
        <div class="div-validar">
          <span [hidden]="myForm.controls.email.valid || (myForm.controls.email.pristine && !submitted)">
            E-Mail inválido
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col s12 l6">
        <label>Telefone: </label>
        <input type="tel" class="forms-econ" name="telefone" formControlName="telefone" pattern="[0-9]" placeholder="(xx)9 9999-99999">
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 l6">
        <label> Motivo do Contato: </label>
        <select name="assunto" formControlName="assunto" class="forms-econ">
          <option value="motivo_01">Motivo 01</option>
          <option value="motivo_02">Motivo 02</option>
          <option value="motivo_03">Motivo 03</option>
          <option value="motivo_03">Motivo 04</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      <div class="col s12">
        <label> Mensagem: </label>
        <textarea name="mensagem" formControlName="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem..." rows="15"> 
        </textarea>
        <div class="div-validar">
          <span [hidden]="myForm.controls.mensagem.valid || (myForm.controls.mensagem.pristine && !submitted)">
            O campo mensagem é obrigatório
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col s12">
        <label> ID: </label>
        <textarea name="id" formControlName="id" placeholder="Mensagem..." rows="15"> 
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <h1> {{myForm.valid | json}} </h1> // <-- Here is where I'm printing the status of the form (always return false)
      <div class="col s12 right-align">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-form">
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here is the component.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {formContato} from './contato.interface';
import {ContatoService} from './contato.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'contato',
  templateUrl: `contato.component.html`,
  providers: [ContatoService]
})
export class ContatoComponent  { 

  public contato:formContato;
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean; 
  public events: any[] = []; 

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private mensagemContato:ContatoService) { } 

    ngOnInit() {  
      this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        nome: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)]],
        email: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        telefone: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        assunto: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        mensagem: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        id: ['']
      })      
    }


    enviarMensagem(model: formContato, isValid: boolean) {
        this.submitted = true;      
        console.log(model, isValid); // -< another way to print the status of the form (always false)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the e-mail and phone validation. They always validate as `false`.

Since you are using a reactive form, I would suggest you move your `pattern` checks to your build of the form, e.g:

```
email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, Validators.pattern(....)]],
```

Then I would assume that you want to inform right from the beginning that fields are required. This can be done in quite a few ways, here I show two possible solutions:

```
<span *ngIf="myForm.get('nome').hasError('required')">
   Name required!
</span><br>
```

or:

```
<span *ngIf="!myForm.controls.nome.pristine">
   Name required!
</span><br>
```

and as mentioned in other answer, you need not to pass the `myForm.valid` in the submit.

I made a **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vD3SLsLHhtUFz209bshC)** for you, where I set another e-mail validation:

```
EMAIL_REGEXP = '^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$';
```

and just a random phone number validation, since I wasn't sure exactly what kind of number validation you need. This one checks that the phone number only contains numbers.

If you want you could also disable the submit button if the form is not valid:

```
<input [disabled]="!myForm.valid" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-form">
```

but that is of course up to you! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It really helped me a lot, thank you very much, great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 , its not required  to pass the `valid` entity on (ngSubmit) , just pass the required form name give to the form group directive .

```
(ngSubmit)="enviarMensagem(myForm)"


enviarMensagem({model, valid }: {model: Object, valid: boolean}) {
    this.submitted = true;      
    console.log(model, valid); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip but I'm still getting false on "valid", do you have any idea of what might be happening?